# Got error : can't be blank, Rails test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, functional-testing

I would like to do testing my rails application, especially on controller, here are the code

customer_controller_test.rb

```
    require 'test_helper'

class CustomersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  setup do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)    
    @role = FactoryGirl.create(:role)
    #puts @role.name
    @permission = FactoryGirl.create(:permission)
    #puts @permission.name
    @role_permission = FactoryGirl.create(:role_permission)
    #puts @role_permission.role_id
    #puts @role_permission.permission_id
    sign_in @user
    @customer = FactoryGirl.create(:customer)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_template 'index'
    assert_not_nil assigns(:customers)
  end

  test "should show article" do
    get :show, :id => @customer.to_param

    assert_response :success
    assert_template 'show'

    assert_not_nil assigns(:customer)
    assert assigns(:customer).valid?
  end

  test "should get new" do
    #login_as(@user)
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

factories.rb <-- setup tha fixtures with factorygirl

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  sequence :email do |n| "admin@admin.admin#{n}" end
  sequence :role_name do |n| n end
  sequence :role_id do |n| n end
  sequence :permission_id do |n| n end

factory :user do |u|
    u.name           "Admin"
    u.role_id        {1}
    u.email          do FactoryGirl.generate(:email) end
    u.password       "123456"
    u.after(:create) do |user|
        user.creator_id  {1} 
        user.save
    end
  end

factory :customer do
    name    "Test customer-name"
    code    "Test customer-code"
    address "Test customer-address"
    phone   "Test customer phone"
  end

factory :permission do
    name "Customer"
  end

  factory :role do
    name do FactoryGirl.generate(:role_name) end
  end
end
```

And I got error

[image: error]

Any idea? Thx before

Comment: "Role can't be blank" is a Rails model validation which fails. It seems your User does not get a Role assigned (which is mandatory it seems).

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the role in FactoryGirl before assigning it to the user.  It looks like you've got a validation error when saving your User record, because it's trying to validate that you've got an actual role assigned.  You don't, because you're attempting to create your role after your user.

Just try switching the two lines in your FactoryGirl "setup" like this:

```
@role = FactoryGirl.create(:role)
@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

Or, check out this link for a more thorough examination of how to use FactoryGirl to test associations:

http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2011/05/13/testing-associations-with-factory-girl/